# React: Overlay on hover without outer container for element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-position

I am developing no-code platform where you can drag and drop HTML elements.

2 things are required:

- user can SELECT each element
- user can style each element through right-side panel (width, length, font-size, ...)

In order for 1) I have used this solution:

**Selector.js**

```
export default Selector = ({children}) => {
    const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

    const mouseOverHandler = (ev) => {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        setIsHovered(true);
    }

    const mouseOutHandler = (ev) => {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        setIsHovered(false);
    }

    return (
        <div className="container" onMouseOver={mouseOverHandler} onMouseOut={mouseOutHandler}>
            {children}
            { isHovered && <div className="overlay"></div> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Selector.css**

```
.container {
    position: relative;               // For .overlay to be absolute
    max-width: fit-content;           // To fit children/content size
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.2);
}
```

**App.js**

```
export default App = () => [
    return (
         <div className="workspace">
             <Selector><Input style={{width: "100%"}} /></Selector>
             <Selector><Block style={{width: "100px"}} /></Selector>
             <Selector><Block style={{width: "100%"}} /></Selector>
         </div>
    );
}
```

**THE PROBLEM** is when I try to set `width:100%` on `Block` component, for example. I want `Block` to stretch full width in `.workspace`, but because `Block` is in `Selector`, it will have `.container` as parent so it will fill only that element, not `.workspace`. With this, I am unable to fulfill 2) requirement.

You can check it here on Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/49cmok2a/2/.
If you set width to 100px on Block it's gonna be block with 100px width, but if you put 100% width, it will just shrink to 1px.

Do you know how to create `Selector`, so it doesn't create parent div on elements. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Partially. I created absolute div block, which has dynamic position and size, so it covers HTML element when hovered, but I am not satisfied with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to overwrite the relative style in the child. You can easy control your Selector's style width just in 2 actions:

First of all, you have to change your max-width: object-fit, this property is used primarily for img or video tags. Change it's property like i did

```
.container{
position: relative;
max-width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Next time you can easy change you Selector's width.

I hope i've got your question correctly, have a good day!

Comment: Thanks Jan for looking into this. If 100% is set for max-width, then overlay is bigger than element that it needs to cover. You can check it on Fiddle if you change that property on link I provided :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the the square you can use 100vw insted of 100% :

```
const App = () => {
    return (
         <div className="workspace">
              <Selector><Input style={{width: "100%"}} /></Selector>
              <Selector><Block style={{width: "100vw"}} /></Selector>
         </div>
    );
}
```

Or make the .workspace 100% of the his parent, make the selector to take 100% of his parent (.workspace) and make the Block or the Input the sizess you want them to be :

```
 <div className="workspace" style={{width: "100%"}} >
              <Selector style={{width: "100%"}} ><Input /></Selector>
              <Selector style={{width: "100%"}} ><Block/></Selector>
         </div>
```

but you need max width to be 100% o n the css file.

```
  max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for looking into this. If you change to 100vw, element will exceed .workspace. Also, if you put 100% for max-width, .overlay will exceed element that it needs to cover. You can check it on Fiddle link in question :)